# Is there a way to obtain a list of Dropbox links in a specific subdirectory?

Tags: dropbox

I need to obtain a list of all of the Dropbox file links in a fairly large sub-directory. I do not want to get them one at a time manually. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you not just share the folder?

Comment: Do you want the public links or the restricted sharing links? Also, are you using the desktop Dropbox client? If you need to do this on the web, we can migrate your question to [webapps.se].

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you asking to get a list of files within a folder/directory that are shared with others? If you go into Dropbox.com click on Links and you get a list of files/folders you've shared... although not for a specific directory. When you look at files/folders, the icon will be different on dropbox.com if the resource is shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you use linux, https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/9192 might be the solution. Just loop through all the files and get the links using the dropbox command line tool.
Something like:

```
# To make sure spaces in the file names won't cause problems
IFS=$(echo "\n\b"); 
files=($(find . -type f));
for i in "${files[@]}"; do
 link=$(dropbox sharelink "$i");
 echo 'file '"$i"' has the shared link '"$link";
done
```

Didn't test this, but I can imagine this working. Hope it helps!